# Shape of Call out for timeline chart

Tags: highcharts

We have three options for call out shape "callout", "square", "circle" in highchart, can we create a custom call out as attached in spac?
[CallOutShape][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLN1Y.png

Comment: Is the label shown in the example a data label or is it an annotation?

Comment: it is a design mockup that need to achieve through data label

Comment: You should be able to achieve it by styling the dataLabel border: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h1zkv3ga/

Comment: I have tried it not working and probably  cause is the comment of Highchart as :
"Texts and labels in Highcharts are given in HTML, but as the HTML is parsed and rendered in SVG, only a subset is supported. The following tags are supported: <b>, <strong>, <i>, <em>, <br/>, <span>. Spans can be styled with a style attribute, but only text-related CSS that is shared with SVG is handled"

Comment: May I see your attempt?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thakurlal_pandey/h8kgwb25/
please look into this

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments - setting the `dataLabel.useHTML` as true and CSS styling allowed to achieve it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nbzd978w/